# Why am I computing $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x \left(\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2} \right)$ wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have to compute $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x \left(\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}\right)$
What I did was write $\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}=\arctan \frac{\frac{1}{x+2}}{1-\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+4x+4}}=\arctan \frac{x^2+4x+4}{3x^2+10x+8}$.
Hence,$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\arctan \frac{x^2+4x+4}{3x^2+10x+8}=\arctan \frac{1}{3}$,so I think that my limit is $\infty$,but it should be $\frac{1}{2}$. Am I not allowed to say that my limit is the product of the limits because $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} x=\infty$?

Comment: Careful, since you are substracting then $arctg(A)-arctg(B) = arctg(\frac{A-B}{1+AB})$ you put $1-AB$ instead

Comment: Yes,that was my mistake,thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From the very beginning, you should obtain
\begin{align}
\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} &-\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}=\arctan \frac{\cfrac{1}{x+2}}{1\color{red}+\cfrac{x^2+x}{(x+2)^2}}=\arctan\frac{x+2}{(x+2)^2+x^2+x}\\[1ex]
&=\arctan\frac{x+2}{(x+2)^2+x^2+x}=\arctan\frac{x+2}{2x^2+5x+4}.
\end{align}
Now, it's simpler to work with *equivalents*:

From Taylor's formula, we now that, near $0$, $\;\arctan u\sim u$, so
$$x\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2}\sim_0 x\cdot\frac{x+2}{2x^2+5x+4}\sim_0x\cdot\frac x{2x^2}=\frac1{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it this way:

Since $\arctan'(1)=1/2$, we have $\arctan(1+\varepsilon)\sim\pi/4+\varepsilon/2$. You can write out a few more terms, involving $\varepsilon^2$, etc., but a moment’s thought convinces you that they won’t contribute to the problem.

Now, $\frac{x+1}{x+2}=1-\frac1{x+2}$, and $\frac x{x+2}=1-\frac2{x+2}$. So we get
\begin{align}
\arctan\left(1-\frac1{x+2}\right)&\sim\frac\pi4-\frac1{2(x+2)}\\
\arctan\left(1-\frac2{x+2}\right)&\sim\frac\pi4-\frac1{x+2}\\
\arctan\left(1-\frac1{x+2}\right)-\arctan\left(1-\frac2{x+2}\right)&\sim\frac1{2(x+2)}\quad\text{, and thus}\\
x\left[\arctan\left(1-\frac1{x+2}\right)-\arctan\left(1-\frac2{x+2}\right)\right]&\sim\frac x{2(x+2)}\longrightarrow\frac12\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$x\left(\arctan\left(1-\frac1{x+2}\right)-\arctan\left(1-\frac2{x+2}\right)\right)$$ can be rewritten

$$(1-2t)\ \frac{\arctan(1-t)-\arctan1+\arctan1-\arctan(1-2t)}t$$ where $t$ tends to $0$. The first factor vanishes and you can see the limit as a combination of derivatives,

$$-\arctan'(1)+2\arctan'(1)=-\frac12+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The MVT implies

$$\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2} = \frac{1}{1+c(x)^2}\cdot \frac{1}{x+2},$$

where $c(x)$ is in the interval $(x/(x+2), (x+1)/(x+2)).$ Multiplying by $x$ gives

$$\frac{1}{1+c(x)^2}\cdot \frac{x}{x+2}.$$

Hopefully it is clear that the first fraction $\to 1/2,$ while the second fraction $\to 1.$ So the limit is $1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Using the hints given by @Lubin and continuing with Taylor expansions
$$\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2}=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{3}{4 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ 
$$\arctan \frac{x}{x+2}=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$x \left(\arctan \frac{x+1}{x+2} -\arctan \frac{x}{x+2} \right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Using $x=8$ and simplifying, the expression is $8 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{86}\right)\approx 0.464593$ while the above expansion gives $\frac{15}{32}\approx 0.468750$.